# Dynamic Flatten - Data Flow ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lot of json files with nested lists that needed to be flatten. The problem is that they are different and I don't want to create one branch for each one of them. How can I execute a Flatten activity with fields "Unroll by" and "Input Columns" dynamic by input parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Unroll By, use "Add Dynamic Content". For the columns, use Rule-based Mapping.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I realized that Unroll by had a dynamic content field like in Copy Activity Mapping. But the columns are the real problem, I have json files with different quantity of nested lists and different "column" names, so If could send an expression as a parameter that would help, but I don't think that is possible because Flatten requires two fields.

Comment: For dynamic names, use "Rule-based mapping" instead of fixed mapping. You can use regex and wildcards there as well as "Deep column traversal" to expand all nested elements.